# Legacy addon usage

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I want to test a legacy addon. I downloaded an older version of firefox, but when I tried to sign the addon, the following message was thrown:

`Starting with Firefox 53, new add-ons on this site can only be WebExtensions`

I also tried to load temporary addon but it did not work.

Does someone have an ideia?

Comment: Try disabling autoupdate on the old version of Firefio prior running it (probably your old version updated to 53 automatically).

Answer (score 0):

i got it.

I downloaded the first developer edition release and set "xpinstall.signatures.required" to false.